# Trouble on saving nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and I am trying to save an "`has_many :through => checkboxes`" class object (I have read the [Quick Tip: has_many :through => checkboxes](http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/) blog post) but I have some troubles on doing that. I would like to create some associations between a *new* article and article categories "owned" by a user (in the below code the `@current_user`) taking advantage of the "magical way" of doing that with Ruby on Rails association models.

In my *models* I have:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_relationships,
    :class_name  => 'Categories::ArticleRelationship',
    :foreign_key => 'article_id',
    :autosave    => true,
    :dependent   => :destroy
  has_many :article_categories,
    :through     => :category_relationships,
    :source      => :article_category,
    :uniq        => true,
    :dependent   => :destroy

  attr_accessible :category_relationship_ids
end

class Categories::ArticleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article,
    :class_name  => 'Article',
    :foreign_key => 'article_id'

  belongs_to :article_category,
    :class_name  => 'Articles::Category',
    :foreign_key => 'category_id'
end
```

In my *view* file I have:

```
...

<% @current_user.article_categories.each do |article_category| %>
  <div>
    <%= check_box_tag :category_relationship_ids, article_category.id, false, :name => 'article[category_relationship_ids][]' %>
    <%= label_tag :article_category, article_category.name %>
  </div>
<% end %>

...
```

that outputs the following HTML code:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="article[category_relationship_ids][]" id="category_relationship_ids">
  <label for="category">comunication</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="article[category_relationship_ids][]" id="category_relationship_ids">
  <label for="category">internal</label>
</div>
```

When I check\select the above two check boxes, (then) I submit the form and I inspect the log file (outputting `@article` and `@article_relationships` data respectively related to `Article` and `Categories::ArticleRelationship` object instances), I get the following:

```
param[:article]        => {"name"=>"Sample title", "category_relationship_ids"=>["5", "6"], ...}
@article               => #<Article id: nil, title: "Sample title", ...>
@article_relationships => [#<Categories::ArticleRelationship id: 5, category_id: 6, article_id: 3, ...>, [#<Categories::ArticleRelationship id: 6, category_id: 4, article_id: 5, ...>
```

*It seems that Ruby on Rails set `Categories::ArticleRelationship id` values to check box values (in the above HTML code: 5 and 6) instead of set those to `nil` (those should be `nil` because `Categories::ArticleRelationship` are not created yet in the database). Furthermore, I don't know where it takes from the `category_id` and `article_id` values (`article_id` values should be `nil` because `@article` instances are not created yet in the database).*

**What is the problem? How can I solve that?**